# which version of PowerShell ISE is required for join-object?

Tags: powershell

When I am trying to use `Join-Object` it is throwing the following error:

> The term 'join-object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of  the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

I am not sure why it is throwing this error.

My current version of Windows PowerShell is 3.0.

Comment: See: [Join-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) in [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one/45483110#45483110)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Join-Object` is not a built in cmdlet in any current version of PowerShell, but several people have written versions of it. For example there's this one which is part of the PSExcel Module:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSExcel/1.0.2/Content/Join-Object.ps1

You could save that script as a .ps1 file on your local machine and then run it. After which you will have the `Join-Object` cmdlet for that session. Or you could install the PSExcel PowerShell module per the instructions [here](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel) as this module contains the `Join-Object` cmdlet.

PowerShell is extensible via modules. To learn more about using modules see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually my requirement is something like this http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/
So i am trying  to join two dataTables

Comment: That is what I linked to, I just linked you to the PowerShell Gallery version of his code vs his blog.

Comment: @Harsh If you open your mentioned link you will come across a `Join-Object` hyperlink. That contains a version of the `Join-Object.ps1` which @Mark is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is not a `PowerShell cmdlet` but rather a `function`. Check [this](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Join-Object.ps1) out. Import this function in your PoSh module and you are good to go.